# Selecting a column of data frame in a shiny app

Tags: r

I try to build a shiny app that creates different plots depending on the selected input. All in all it works out. The only problem is when I try to find the minimum of a certain row I am giving a non-numeric argument to a binary operator.

Here is my code:

```
    server = function(input,output,session){
  output$variableOutput = renderUI({
    selectInput("VariableInput",
                "Variable auswählen",
                choices = colnames(training),
                selected = "X1_P")
  })

  output$coolPlot = renderPlot({
    if (is.null(input$VariableInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }  

    ggplot(data = training) + 
      geom_boxplot(aes_string(x="flag",
                       y=input$VariableInput,
                       fill="flag"),
                   outlier.shape = NA) + 
      guides(fill=FALSE)+
      scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Nicht-Ziel", "Ziel")) +
#here is the problem!!!
      #coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(input$VariableInput),
       #                        quantile(input$VariableInput)[4] + IQR(input$VariableInput, 
        #                                                            na.rm = FALSE, type = 7)*1.9)) +
      stat_boxplot(aes_string(x="flag",
                       y=input$VariableInput,
                       fill="flag"),
                   geom ='errorbar') + 
      theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=15,
                                        face = "bold"),
            axis.text.y  = element_text(size=12),
            axis.text.x  = element_text(size=12),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size=15,
                                        face = "bold"))+
      labs(x = paste(variables[i]),
           y = "Ausprägung der Variable")
  })

  output$coolTable = renderDataTable({ 
    training
  })
}
```

I left the code which causes problems out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's `quantile()` function that needs numeric:

```
quantile(as.numeric(input$VariableInput))
```